# can i make a Leaflet marker draggable on a single click?

Tags: leaflet, marker

I want a leaflet marker to be draggable on a single click, I passed the draggable property as true so the marker moves after a double click nonetheless I would like to use the map in a phone where the double click isn't the more intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable dragging for a existing marker call `marker.dragging.enable()`:

```
marker.on('click',(e)=>{
  e.target.dragging.enable()
})
``´
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but enabling the draggable option this way keeps making the markers draggable after a double click instead of a single click.

Comment: you can add a listener `dblclick` and disable dragging with `... .disable()`

Comment: You were right, the problem was that i did disable the map dragging just before adding the marker.